# What file stores the theme that XFCE uses on boot?

Tags: themes, livecd, xfce, liveusb, gtk

I'm working on a custom live boot of Debian with XFCE and I want to boot to a specific theme by default. I have the theme loaded onto the ISO so it's available when it boots, but it still boots to the default theme. Where can I set it to use the themes I want on boot?

Comment: Have you tried editing `/usr/share/xfwm4/defaults` file? There's an option `theme=Default`. Maybe editing this would change the theme on boot. Also can't you change the theme from the settings?